# Moving a dot on python

Tags: python, move

I am wondering how to move a dot around on the screen. like in the classic game called worm.
the keys of choice would be w for up s for down a for left and d for right.
I am using python 2.5.4

p.s I am a noob a python

Comment: I would look at curses for text base game, or pygame for graphical

Answer (score 1):

You can use from [pygame](http://www.pygame.org)!

[this](http://blog.simpliplant.eu/simple-snake-game-in-python/) is simple snake game that made by pygame!

or use this code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 800, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
position=[20,20]
white=[255,255,255]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop=False
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.D_KEY:
                position[0]+=20


    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,[255,0,0],position,100,3)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```